# Do I need a Direct Airside Transit Visa when I have a Standard Visitor visa for UK?

Tags: visas, uk, lhr, pakistani-citizens, datv

I'm a Pakistani national residing in Saudi Arabia due to visit Finland. I have a valid Schengen visa and a multiple-entry visitor visa for United Kingdom. I'm flying with British Airways both ways and have layovers at Heathrow Airport for 2 - 3 hours.

Do I need a Direct Airside Transit Visa?

Comment: Please see the linked article under the section "Update 25 July 2015: Visa Seniority"

Comment: @pnuts not so much 'evasive' as 'vague'. Yes, it's deliberate.

Comment: @pnuts get some sleep, honestly, take a break and rest.

Comment: You **never** need separate documents to transit a country's Airport if you can enter that country. Otherwise it would mean that you're allowed to clear immigration, but not remain in the transit area. In taht case, you could transit if you clear immigration and re-clear security, but not if you go directly to the next gate. Makes no sense, does it?